# exactness of a 1-form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-calculus

This may be a trivial question. If so, apologies in advance.

Let a $1$-form $\omega$ be given. Suppose that for any line segments $C_1=[i,j]$, $C_2=[j,k]$, $C_3=[i,k]$, we have that 
$\int_{C_1} \omega + \int_{C_2} \omega = \int_{C_3} \omega$.

My question is whether this implies that $\omega$ is exact. If this were true for any curves $C_1,C_2,C_3$, I believe the answer would be affirmative. I want to make sure that restricting attention to finitely (or countably) many line segments is without loss of generality.

Comment: Math.StackExchange is more appropriate for elementary math questions.

Comment: May I ask why you need this?

Comment: I'm reading a paper, whose assumptions basically correspond to  path-independence over line segments. I'm trying to obtain an easier way of proving their result leveraging equivalence between closedness/exactness. For that I need to establish that path independence over finitely many line segments suffices for exactness.

Comment: Have you already made any initial effort to prove the result or find a counterexample? Sometimes one or the other is reasonably easy, as long as you keep an open mind about whether it's true or not.

Comment: The question is not clearly stated anyway. Are $C_i$ line segments or curves? Just check any textbook in Calculus 3, look for path independent line integrals and potential functions.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz I think the question explicitly states $C_i$ are line segments.

Comment: @DeaneYang, thanks for your message. My thinking was the following: I can approximate any curve with line segments. If the components of $\omega$ are continuous functions this should be sufficient to establish the result. I'm less clear if the continuity of the components is necessary though.

Comment: What regularity are you assuming for the 1-forms?

Comment: Is the domain of the 1-form an arbitrary open set in Euclidean space?

Answer (score 4):

**The answer is no.**
This answer is similar in the spirit to that of Ben McKay, but with all details provided. Consider the form 
$$
\omega = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\, dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\, dy
$$
on the annulus $\Omega=\{ (x,y):\, 1<x^2+y^2<1.1\}$. This form is closed, but not exact, because the integral along a circle around zero equals $2\pi$.

Any triangle in $\Omega$ will have the interior contained in $\Omega$, because the annulus $\Omega$ is so thin that the triangle cannot go around the origin. Since the form is closed, it is exact in a neighborhood of the triangle and hence the integral along the triangle equals zero showing that 
$$
\int_{C_1} \omega + \int_{C_2} \omega = \int_{C_3} \omega.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Take the differential form $\omega$ to be $d\theta$ in polar coordinates, so that $\omega$ extends to a unique smooth 1-form on the punctured plane (punctured at the origin). Remove from the plane a horizontal line segment centred at the origin and of length 2. Remove a similar vertical one. Then remove the diagonal lines, except for segments centred at the origin of length 1/2. If you draw the picture, I think you can see that there is no triangle around the origin lying in the resulting domain, and that any triangle in that domain lies in a half space, so has integral zero. Of course, this is not a proof; there are some details left to work out.